# Fourier Analysis: Prove $c_n=a_nb_n$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I am stuck in the middle of this proof:

> Let $f,g \in E[-\pi,\pi]$ be periodic functions with periods of $2\pi$, where
>
> $f(x)$ ~ $\sum_{n=-\inf}^{\inf}a_ne^{inx}$
>
> $g(x)$ ~ $\sum_{n=-\inf}^{\inf}b_ne^{inx}$
>
> $\forall x\in R: h(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)g(t)dt$ | $h(x)$ ~ $\sum_{n=-\inf}^{\inf}c_ne^{inx}$
>
> Prove that $c_n=a_nb_n$
>
> ($\forall n \in Z$)

Here is what I've got so far:

By definition, $c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)e^{-inx}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)g(t)dte^{-inx}dx$

$c_n=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)e^{-inx}dx)g(t)dt$

However, in order to finish the proof, I need to, presumably using periodicity, say that

$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(t)dt = a_nb_n$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there

\begin{eqnarray}
c_n&=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)e^{-inx}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\color{blue}{f(x-t)}\color{red}{g(t)}dt\right\}~e^{-inx}~dx \\
&=& \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \color{blue}{\sum_{k} a_ke^{ik (x-t)}}\color{red}{\sum_l b_l e^{il t}}e^{-inx} ~dx dt \\
&=& \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \sum_{k,l} a_k b_l e^{ikx}e^{-i(k-l)t}dt dx \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \sum_{k,l} a_k b_l e^{-i(n - k)x} \color{orange}{\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i(k-l)t}dt\right\}} dx \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \sum_{k,l} a_k b_l e^{-i(n - k)x} \color{orange}{\delta_{kl}} dx \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_k a_kb_k e^{-i(n - k)x}dx \\
&=&\sum_k a_k b_k \color{magenta}{\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i(n-k)t}dx\right\}} \\
&=& \sum_k a_k b_k \color{magenta}{\delta_{nk}}
= a_n b_n
\end{eqnarray}